# Pattern/Matcher in Java?

Tags: java, regex, newline

I have a certain text in Java, and I want to use pattern and matcher to extract something from it. This is my program:

```
public String getItemsByType(String text, String start, String end) {

    String patternHolder;
    StringBuffer itemLines = new StringBuffer();

    patternHolder = start + ".*" + end;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternHolder);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        itemLines.append(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())
                + "\n");
    }

    return itemLines.toString();
}
```

This code works fully WHEN the searched text is on the same line, for instance:

```
String text = "My name is John and I am 18 years Old"; 

getItemsByType(text, "My", "John");
```

immediately grabs the text "My name is John" out of the text. However, when my text looks like this:

```
String text = "My name\nis John\nand I'm\n18 years\nold"; 

getItemsByType(text, "My", "John");
```

It doesn't grab anything, since "My" and "John" are on different lines. How do I solve this?

Comment: You should change `      itemLines.append(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())
                + "\n");` to `itemLines.append(matcher.group()); itemLines.append('\n');`

You shouldn't do string concatenations using + when you have string buffer at hand. Also I would use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Pattern.compile(patternHolder, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), the `DOTALL` flag means:

> Enables dotall mode.
>
> In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.

Comment: Thanks you sir, that was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pattern.compile(patternHolder, Pattern.DOTALL)` to compile the pattern. This way the dot will match the newline. By default, newline is treated in a special way and not matched by the dot.